# Python CGI WebServer

Tags: python-3.x

I need to host a server in python capable of CGI which takes the url parameters, sends it the index.py, executes and return the output to the browser. Is there an easy solution? I could not find good tutorials on this topic.

Comment: Have you looked into Flask along with an API service (to handle the URL parsing?

Comment: @S3DEV Thanks. It was extremely easy to setup. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, it deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above:

Perhaps check out [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) as your web service.
Here is a link to the [getting started guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

We have this running along side a internally developed API service (also running on Flask) which parses the URL/URI requests from the Flask web service.

Comment: This saved me a ton of time. Thanks!! :)

Comment: @BhavyaGupta - My pleasure, glad it has helped you.